# Why the ItemsControl doesn't show all

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have an ItemsControl.

```
    <DockPanel Height="280">
        <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" >
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsControl Height="400" Name="icTodoList" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Name="ToDoList">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime, FallbackValue=' '}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConnectedTime, FallbackValue=' '}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisconnectedTime, FallbackValue=' '}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DialingResult, FallbackValue=' '}" Grid.Row="3"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
```

In my MainViewModel.cs, I have:

```
    public class MainViewModel : NotifyUIBase
    public ObservableCollection<Calls> items = new ObservableCollection<Calls>();
    public ObservableCollection<Calls> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

And:

```
 public class NotifyUIBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    // Very minimal implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged matching msdn
    // Note that this is dependent on .net 4.5+ because of CallerMemberName
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Then in my code behind:
       MainViewModel _dataContext;

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _dataContext = new MainViewModel();
        this.DataContext = _dataContext;


Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict = RunScript();
Calls c = new Calls();
c.StartTime = dict["StartTime"];
c.ConnectedTime = dict["ConnectedTime"];
c.DisconnectedTime = dict["DisconnectedTime"];
c.DialingResult = dict["DialingResult"] + '\n';
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
{
    if (c != null)
        _dataContext.Items.Add(c);
});
```

***EDIT:***

To add calls, I used `ActionBlock` in a async `Task` method.

```
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<T>(
t=>
  {
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict = RunScript(t);
        Calls c = new Calls();
        // get c from dict
         Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
         {
             if (c != null)
              _dataContext.Items.Add(c);
     });
      },
         executionDataflowBlockOptions);
        // link a BufferBlock to this ActionBlock
           await actionBlock.Completion;
```

Suppose I have 100 calls, the expected output on the screen should have 100 sets data. I am sure that they are not null. However it only displays 6 data sets, why?

Comment: Instead of `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` try using `Dispatcher.Invoke` to add items to collection.

Comment: @RohitVats, same result I got.

Comment: I don't see any loop to add items in collection. From where you are calling this method?

Comment: @RohitVats, to save space, I didn't show all codes. It is inside in a `ActionBlock`, which is .Net 4.5--TPL Dataflow. `var consumerBlock = new ActionBlock<T>({r=>{ Calls c = new Calls();// blah blah.},
executionDataflowBlockOptions);`

Comment: you are instantiating dict twice. I suppose RunScript(t) already returns a new Dictionary<string,string>()

Comment: Obviously there is something wrong about ActionBlock and its surrounding codes. If you post more code relating to async and await parts it would be easier to say.

Comment: @Bizz, yes. I want to RunScript(t) already returns a new Dictionary<string,string>() each time. Say I have 100 calls, it should have 100 dictionaries. There is no more code around `ActionBlock` except `MaxDegreeOfParallelism=4`.

Comment: Then you should write `var dict = RunScript(t)` and remove the first line. Also MaxDegreeOfParallelism=4 should be responsible for this behavior. What if you set it to 100?

Comment: @Bizz, I changed it but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, An ItemsControl doesn't work that well with a ScrollViewer, that's why I am not seeing all items. By removing the ScrollViewer element and add one to the control template of the ItemsControl by setting its Template property:

```
<DockPanel Height="280">
        <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" >
            <ItemsControl Name="icTodoList" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Name="ToDoList">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime, FallbackValue=' '}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConnectedTime, FallbackValue=' '}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisconnectedTime, FallbackValue=' '}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DialingResult, FallbackValue=' '}" Grid.Row="3"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.Template>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: FWIW, I'd also wrap your ItemsControl within a Grid.